# Loop for sending hits to Google Analytics via Measurement Protocol

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am new to Apps Script and I am trying to send a set of hits to Google Analytics, via Measurement Protocol. The hits are validated and everything is working, but I am missing the part of the loop, in order to send many requests and not only the first row, which it is what is hapenning right now.

I am pretty sure the for loop is not working, but I am struggling with this.

```
function measurementprotocolrequest() {
  var nsheet = "1nzUmSH1QTyDKxx5sBkGs5G4uV_JHTkPcHL64sUTbbqY";
  var query = SpreadsheetApp.openById(nsheet).getSheetByName("Query");

  
  var lr = query.getLastRow()
  var data = query.getRange("AA2:AA" + lr).getValue()
  Logger.log(data)
  for(var i = 0;i<=lr;i++){
    
    var options = {
      "method" : "post",
      "payload" : data
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google-analytics.com/collect", options);}
  
}
```

The goal would be to send the set of rows on column AA, and not only the first row (see image below, please):

[image: Google Spreadsheet PrintScreen]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether you are still looking for the solution, I proposed a modified script as an answer. If you still need the solution, could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose the following modification.

#### Modification points:

- In order to retrieve the values of cells "AA2:AA", please use `getValues()` instead of `getValue()`.
- The values retrieved by `getValues()` are 2 dimensional array. And in your case, the values are retrieved from one column. So in this case, the values are like `[[AA2],[AA3],,,]`.
- In your script, the loop is done from `0` to `lr`. But in the case of `query.getRange("AA2:AA" + lr).getValue()`, `data` is the value of the cell of `AA2`. So the value from the same cell is used. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var lr = query.getLastRow()
var data = query.getRange("AA2:AA" + lr).getValue()
Logger.log(data)
for(var i = 0;i<=lr;i++){

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : data
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google-analytics.com/collect", options);}
```

#### To:

```
var lr = query.getLastRow();
var data = query.getRange("AA2:AA" + lr).getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": data[i][0]
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google-analytics.com/collect", options);
}
```

Or, when you want to use the GET method, I think that the following modification can be also used.

```
var lr = query.getLastRow();
var data = query.getRange("AA2:AA" + lr).getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?" + data[i][0]);
}
```

#### Note:

- Above modified scripts suppose that `data` can be used for Measurement Protocol. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Measurement Protocol Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference)